# Maven: Mission versions in dependencies

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am using Maven since about 1 year (Jdk 11, Mvn 3.6).

When I am looking into libraries I try to use then most of the time there is a dependency in the "Getting started" or the Docs. So you can simply copy it into your own pom.xml.

But most of them do not have a version-element in it.

When I do the mvn-compile then I get an error because of missing dependencies.dependency.version.

If I add a version manually (after getting it in Mavens repository), then all is ok.

So why is that?

Is my Maven too old and newer versions support the omit of the version?
Is it best practise to because anyone knows to lookup a version?

Comment: You can't omit the version of a dependency - it's a required property in any version of Maven. You need to look it up in Maven Central each time you add a dependency. The reason someone doesn't publish the version of their library is because they don't want to update the documentation every time they release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any dependency management tool, including Maven, require you to specify a dependency version. This is to avoid ambiguity and to not break your project, since future versions might remove / modify functionality you might depend on. You can get some additional information [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution).

Documentation may not specify a version, since the docs *might* make some assumptions:

1. The end-user (you) already know how to look up available versions.
2. The end-user (you) probably want to use the latest, and no need to update the docs for every single version that is released.